# Few questions about using a proxy with a vpn

Tags: vpn, proxy

I know that you can connect to a vpn but also connect to a proxy whilst at it

What the benefit of connecting to a proxy and a vpn at the same time?

Does it display the proxy ip, or the VPN ip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What actually happens when you connect to VPN  is,  you give data to VPN server and ask it to  give it to Proxy. VPN  takes your package and gives it to proxy server. Then proxy server sends the request to target server (like **http://google.com**). So what the actual IP that SERVER (google in this case) uses, depends on Which one has sent the request to server.
Its benefits that I can tell:

1. It would be harder to track something in the net
2. Lower speed connection!